# Scroll lag in coordinate layout with viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

When switching pages in viewpager under appbarlayout the scroll does not work properly. Since the `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"` is used the appbarlayout should scroll smoothly out of screen when viewpager below is scrolled. 
Check the video (after 12 seconds) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_gY-7SiDiFs

Here is a gif of the issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KaAH.jpg

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Here is the layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                android:id="@+id/detail_main_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:elevation="0dp">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">
                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@+id/detail_thumbnail_root_layout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@android:color/black"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:focusable="true"
                            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

                        </FrameLayout>
                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/fdsafsda123"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="?android:windowBackground"
                        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

                </RelativeLayout>

                </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                    android:background="@color/transparent_background_color"
                    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
                    app:tabGravity="center"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp">

                </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hide the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` by adding another flag like this:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
```

And to hide `RelativeLayout`, you can try this:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

And you'll need this to pin your view:

```
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
```

Only `scroll` flag might not be enough.

Comment: Thanks. Even after trying all theses combinations the recycler view starts to scroll under the appbarlayout and appbarlayout scrolls very slowly/laggy.

Comment: You'll need to add more info-codes to check that `RecyclerView` too. Maybe adding a gif? Also have you tried to check the behavior on a real device? Is it working as expected by those flags? That might be another issue..

Comment: Try using this: `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"` and see what happens for the collapsible views.

Comment: same issue. Also I want the views to simply scroll off the screen. I do not want snapping/enterAlways behaviour.

Comment: It works fine when I have only one page in the viewpager. The problem happens only when I switch pages in viewpager.